# i need to make a java.net url fetch with a json request. Please tell me how can i call that using java in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, httpurlconnection, google-groups-api, google-directory-api

This is my HTTP URL

```
POST HTTPS://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/group
MY json request 
{
   "email": "sales_group@example.com",
   "name": "Sales Group",
   "description": "This is the Sales group."
}
```

I am using Directory API to create groups.

I never used URL fetch so far so i am not familiar with that. 
Please help me how can i do that..

THIS IS MY ANSWER I POSTED AFTER 2 HOURS. stackoverflow did not allow me to to answer my own question before 8 hours since i have less than 10 reputation, so forgive me for long question.
I tried this..
    i was struggling a bit in passing json as parameter. here is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONException;
import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DirectoryApiExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
        static Logger log = gger.getLogger(DirectoryApiExampleServlet.class.getName());
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
     URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups");
     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("email", "abc@gmail.com");
        json.put("name", "Test Group");
        json.put("description", "this is a test group");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    writer.write(json.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    log.info("connection.getResponseCode()"+connection.getResponseCode());        
}
```

}

But it is giving 401 response which is not expected.

Where am i making mistake???

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation available on how to make a POST request. An example is also provided. Check out the following section : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet#Using_HttpURLConnection

Comment: 401 is due to the fact that you are unauthorized. Before you make a call to the API, you will need to login with the correct credentials that is allowed to execute that action. Please refer to the documentation for the specific API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add authorization header with Access Token

Authorization : Bearer ya29.vQE48oltidkR